# Install only amd64 packages where possible

Tags: apt, package-management, 64-bit, 32-bit

When I try to install any package via apt it downloads both amd64 and i386 packages.
 I want to download and install only amd64 packages when available and i386 only when amd64 packages are not available.

How to do it?

Comment: which package for apt downloads both?

Comment: Can you give an example of a package that installs both platforms?

Comment: Yes, please do as @Pilot6 said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on a 64-bit platform (which I think you're on), `apt` will only download and install 64-bit packages by default. You can have `apt` install 32-bit packages by explicitly enabling that using `dpkg --add-architecture i386` command. But even in that case, a 64-bit installation will only 64-bit packages by default. You have to use `:i386` after the package name to install 32-bits.

However, You may sometimes notice apt downloading `i386` packages whilst you wanted to install 64-bits. This can happen for several reasons

- `apt` can only find 32-bit version for that package.
- Some packages depend on 32-bit versions. Wine is a good example for this case.